# Fetching value from single row queryset

Tags: django, iteration, django-queryset

I have a query as below :

```
entry = TableModel.objects.only('id', 'name', 'age').filter(key='ABC')
```

Now, i know that this query will return me a single row.This i am ensuring through some backend logic.

In general cases, i would extract the value via iterating through `for` loop like :

```
for data in entry:
    print data
```

But since there is a single row for sure, is there any way to directly fetch the value and avoid the `loop` iteration.Something like :

```
  entry.id          #OR
  entry['id']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use get instead of filter;

```
entry = TableModel.objects.only('id', 'name', 'age').get(key='ABC')
```

Refer this
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/